# rake aborted couldn't find file twitter/bootstrap while deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to deploy an app that works fine in development, but when I push it to heroku with $git push heroku master , the rake assets:precompile fails because  "couldn't find file twitter/bootstrap". (error raised by application.js)

I've already googled the problem and found a huge variety of answers but none of these work for me:
[Heroku deploy fails after upgrading to bootstrap 2.0.1 via twitter-bootstrap-rails gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423067/heroku-deploy-fails-after-upgrading-to-bootstrap-2-0-1-via-twitter-bootstrap-rai)

[Couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap' in Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047478/rails-app-with-twitter-bootstrap-works-in-development-but-not-in-production)

[Rails3 couldn't find file 'bootstrap'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213599/rails3-couldnt-find-file-bootstrap)

-i've tried to add config.assets.precompile = false

can anyone help me to figure out the problem? i can't really understand.
Thank you.

here is the Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

group :development do
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => "git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git", :branch => "static"
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.3'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
```

The application.css:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

and this is the application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: have you uploaded you new files upp to github, and then to heroku?

Comment: Do git status to see if there are any files left to commit

Comment: try restarting heroku. `$ heroku restart`

Comment: yes i've pushed files on github before, there are no new files to commit. Now i'll try to restart heroku

Comment: unfortunately neither heroku restart works

Comment: before "deploy:assets:precompile", :bundle_install

I had to add that to my capistrano file to get things working.  I don't know what that translates into in terms of your environment, but it looks like more crap from Rails asset pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by using following steps:

1. Move **twitter-bootstrap-rails** gem from outside of :assets in gemfile.
2. Update **twitter-bootstrap-rails** gem version **2.2.6** or 
   just paste below line in your gemfile.
   **gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'**

**(or)**

if twitter-bootstrap-rails 2.2.6 is not working then 
Use **twitter-bootstrap-rails gem latest version**.

Comment: OP should select this as the solution

Answer (score 1):

Why are you including 2 times bootstrap?

```
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap
```

U should include it just in the 2nd way (`//= require bootstrap`) and it should work properly.

**Edit**: I'm just using `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.2'` therefore I just need `//= require bootstrap` ..if you're using also the other gem you just need the 1st line and the problem I can imagine still remains. Have you tried without using the static branch?

Comment: i tried but now the error is "application.css has already been required"

Comment: it, still don't work; i have to use the  static branch because else in windows, when i run bundle install, i receive an error about therubyracer

Answer (score 0):

in my case remove application.css.scss resolve the issue (i don't get errors anymore when i'm tring to deploy to heroku) but when i try to access to my app heroku says "We're sorry, but something went wrong"

running heroku rake db:migrate at the end works fine for me and now everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

read this: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/123

try to:

1. remove bootstrap files from app/assets/javascript and app/assets/stylesheets
2. rails g bootstrap:install
3. push to heroku

also, try to move the gem out the assets group

edit: nvm, didn't see your answer, you should approve it ;)